# Editing the PATH in PASE

Tags: unix-shell, ibm-midrange

I am doing a some PHP development on an IBMi running ZendServer6. I have to call PHP by its full path of /usr/local/zendsvr6/bin/php-cli. Is there a dotfile I can edit in my home directory or some configuration change I could make from the greenscreen, or request to someone with QSECOFR make to add that path to my startup path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The default shell for PASE for i is ksh](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzalf/rzalfpase.htm), and if that's what you're using you can simply edit the `.profile` file in your home directory like any other system. For example, add:

```
PATH=/usr/local/zendsvr6/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

Then log out and log back in.