# How to edit environment variable in PASE without VI or NANO etc

Tags: ibm, environment-variables, ibm-midrange

I'm new to IBMi but am relatively familiar with UNIX like OS's.  I don't have VI or NANO in PASE on IBMi, I can't seem to download and install either of them either.  I found `EDTF` [here](http://www.itjungle.com/mpo/mpo031402-story04.html) but when I use it, it's states command not found.

Is there a built in text editor I can use? Or is my only option [RPM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1011037)?

I want to edit my environment variables but don't see a .profile or .bash-profile in my home directory.  I used `ls -la` and see other files which begin with dots, but not those.  Which files do I have to edit if these don't exist?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/691019/126632 If no `.profile` file exists, you can simply create one. Also, `vi` should already be available to you; if it's not, it might not be [in your PATH](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzalf/rzalfpase.htm).

Comment: I saw that question and answer.  Did not realize it doesn't exist until I created it.  Figured since the question was from 2011 something changed and that is why it didn't exist for me.  Thank you, I'll try creating it to see if it works.

Comment: That question is from 2015, this year.

Comment: Ahh, I saw May 11 and that was why I though 2011.  Quick question though, is there a built in editor I can use to create and edit a file?

Comment: In the worst case you could use `cat`. But I would go find the system administrator and ask where `vi` is. It definitely should be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>F21</kbd> (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd> from a 5250 terminal or <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> from a VT terminal) will open a command prompt where you can execute the [EDTF](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/cl/edtf.htm) command.  The [WRKLNK](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/cl/wrklnk.htm) command is a handy file manager utility as well.

Here's a starting point for documentation on the [Shells and utilities](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzahg/rzahgshell.htm) available.

Keep in mind that most applications are based on the native OS/400 environment which is completely different than the POSIX/IFS environment.  If you are thinking it is just another UNIX like system you're going to have a lot of difficulty.